# SizeToContent Fills Screen with RichTextBox and FlowDocumentScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I'm trying to show a FlowDocument in a WPF form and have tried both RichTextBox and FlowDocumentScrollViewer.  I also require that the window resizes to be able to show all text.
Unfortunately, when I set SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" for the Window itself, no matter what content I put in the FlowDocument, the window expands to the full width of all my displays!  The height seems to resize fine, however.

Anyone know how to get it to resize properly? Looked all over and cannot figure out how to get this going...
XAML below:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControls.SecureConfirmationDialog"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SecureConfirmationDialog" 
        MinHeight="120" MinWidth="200" 

        Height="120" Width="300" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="flowMsg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="3" IsToolBarVisible="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
        <TextBox Name="txtConfirm" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Testing" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3" />
        <Button Name="btnOK" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3" Width="50" Click="btnOK_Click"  />
        <Button Name="btnCancel" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3" Width="50" Click="btnCancel_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Its a little confusing what you're wanting the window to do. Do you want everything to always show without the scroll bar? Try changing the 1st row height to 'auto' maybe

Comment: Don't really care about the scrollbars, just the only way I could do it without showing the FlowDocumentReader toolbar as well.

Answer (score 1):

`SizeToContent` only "works" if the content is actually bounded, in this case however the Grid, which is the content of `Window`, has no size restrictions so it will try to get all the space it can get, the window responds by giving it as much space as fits the screen.

If you want to prevent this you would need to make the container for your document to size to their content which might be impossible if the document does not have any bounds itself and also behaves in a give-me-all-you-have manner.